# How to compare day of week to string in IF statements?

Tags: date, plsql

I need to use IF to compare the date(day format) to the string 'SUNDAY' which is today.
If today is Sunday, the code prints still prints the ELSE statement
Today is Sunday, but it still says it's not Sunday.

[image: my pl/sql code]

Expecting the IF statement and not ELSE statement

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of link to code screenshot

Comment: I tried but it keeps saying that my code is not properly formatted, which it is not true.

Answer (score 3):

The output of `to_char(datetime)` is blank-padded by default:

```
SQL> select '"'||to_char(sysdate,'DAY')||'"' as actual_value from dual;

ACTUAL_VALUE
--------------------------------------
"SUNDAY   "
```

You can avoid this with the `fm` modifier:

```
SQL> select '"'||to_char(sysdate,'fmDAY')||'"' as actual_value from dual;

ACTUAL_VALUE
--------------------------------------
"SUNDAY"
```

However, it is safer to specify a date language, in case the session is not set to default to English (and fractionally more efficient to specify a shorter format):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = German;

SQL> select '"'||to_char(sysdate,'fmDAY')||'"' as actual_value from dual;

ACTUAL_VALUE
------------------------------------------
"SONNTAG"
```

Shorter ('DY' instead of 'DAY') and safer (ensures 'SUN' not 'SON', 'DIM' etc):

```
SQL> select '"'||to_char(sysdate,'DY','nls_date_language = English')||'"' as actual_value from dual;

ACTUAL_VALUE
--------------
"SUN"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `TO_CHAR(..., 'DAY')`. It returns a string of fixed length regardless of the day of the week. The length depends on `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`. For example, for English, the longest day-of-the-week name is `WEDNESDAY` which is nine characters. Then, for any other day of the week, `TO_CHAR(..., 'DAY')` returns a string of the same length (nine characters for English), by right-padding with spaces as needed.

The simplest way to fix your code is to wrap the left-hand side of your comparisons within `TRIM()`.

There are a bunch of odd things in your code (for example, in the `ELSE` branch you should say "today is not SUNDAY", not "today is not ... whatever the TO_CHAR returned"), but that's not what you asked. The answer to your question, and no more, is given above.